# How to compute the mean and standard deviation of columns ignoring NaN values

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mean

I have a dataframe of doubles with some NaN/Null/NA values:

```
val dfDouble = Seq(
  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0),
  (1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  (1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  (1.0, NaN, 0.0, 2.0)).toDF("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4")
```

I would like to compute the mean, standard deviation, and # of non-null observations for each column, but it seems like the regular aggregate functions in spark returns `NaN` when there is a `NaN` value:

```
dfDouble.select(dfDouble.columns.map(c => mean(col(c))) :_*).show
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |avg(m1)|avg(m2)|avg(m3)|avg(m4)|
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |    1.0|    NaN|    0.5|    1.5|
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+
dfDouble.select(dfDouble.columns.map(c => stddev(col(c))) :_*).show
// +---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
// |stddev_samp(m1)|stddev_samp(m2)|   stddev_samp(m3)|   stddev_samp(m4)|
// +---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
// |            0.0|            NaN|0.5773502691896257|1.2909944487358056|
// +---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
```

How can I compute the mean, standard deviation, and # of non-null observations EXCLUDING `NaN` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `NaN` values by `null` before applying `mean` and `stddev` functions:

```scala
val df = dfDouble.na.fill(dfDouble.columns.map((_, "null")).toMap)

df.select(df.columns.map(c => mean(col(c))) :_*).show

//+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//|avg(m1)|avg(m2)|avg(m3)|avg(m4)|
//+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//|    1.0|    2.0|    0.5|    1.5|
//+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```